# How to track File Upload in struts2?

Tags: file, file-upload, struts2

I am using struts2 file upload tag to upload files,

```
<s:form id="upform" action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            Select file
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:file name="upload"/>
        </td>
        <td><s:submit/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</s:form>
```

its working fine but the problem is, i want to track that, how much data is uploaded like say i have 5 mb file and i put it on uploading so how can i know that how much data is uploaded out of 5 mb or percentage.
i want to track the progress of upload. There are number of jquery/ajax file uploaders, but i want to do it with struts2 file upload tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i don't see a direct way to do this except if you go to use either Jquery/Ajax method or go for some already plugin which take care of this.

S2 under the hood use [Apache Common File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to perform File Upload work for you, and its interceptor will provide a wrapper so that we as end user are out of the complexity of the process.
If you want to track the progress you can take help of [ProgressListener](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/ProgressListener.html).The ProgressListener may be used to display a progress bar or do stuff like that.